# How to insert multiple values at a time in Auto incremented column using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using Postgres database and sqlalchemy core. I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS id_generation (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY)
```

and I am trying to insert multiple values in the id column using below query. number_of_ids can be in multiple of 1000.

```
for _ in range(number_of_ids):
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO id_generation VALUES (DEFAULT)')
```

I just want to know is there any other way to write this query using Sqlalchemy core. How we can optimize it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using psycopg2 as the connector, you can pass a list of empty dictionaries to `conn.execute`, corresponding to the number of rows to be inserted, and SQLAlchemy will emit a single `INSERT` statement with multiple `VALUES` clauses.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

...

vals = [{} for _ in range(100)]

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text(INSERT INTO id_generation VALUES (DEFAULT)'), vals)
```

SQLAlchemy makes use of psycopg2's [fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers), as documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers).